# Statements in python f string format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am thinking of using a statement inside a the curly braces of string format to alter the string based on a variable
For eg:.

```
a=1
print(f'a is {"True" if a==1 else "False"}')
```

Is this considered a bad practice or is it ok.

Comment: For your specific example you can write `print(f'a is {a==1}')`

Comment: what if a==2? would you condider this to be False?

Comment: it depends on values you are passing. If all values except zero are True: `f'a is {a!=0}'`

Comment: Opinion based..

Comment: Technically fine, but places a lexical burden on the reader. You also need to now pay attention to the use of quotes. I would break it out by setting a variable on a separate line.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki , StevenRumbalski :The code snippet in the question is just an example to make the question clear and not an actual use case.My query is regarding the usage of conditional statements inside the braces.

Comment: your code is perfectly fine for such simple case. If you have multiple options that would need an if/elif/else, then I would use a dictionary and `.get()` with a default value: `options = {1: "One", 2: "Two"}`    `print(f"a is {options.get(a, default='something else')}")`   This will print "a is One", "a is Two" or "a is something else" depending on the value of a

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is technically working.

As Steven mentioned in this case you can use `print(f'a is {a==1}')`

In the more general cases I wouldn't recommend this. I like to separate my code into smaller blocks and not to have too much logic in one line. It might seems nice, but takes very long to understand long lines with a complex logic. You are welcome to run `import this` to see the `Zen of Python`.

I would do:

```
a=1
is_a_eq_1 = a==1  # or "True" if a==1 else "False" for a more general case
print(f"a is {is_a_eq_1}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=1
print(f'a is {"True" if a==1 else "False"}')
```

I don't see anything bad with your example.

It is just a ternary operator checking condition inside the curly braces.

A link to ternary operator question:

[Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operatory)

@StevenRumbalski also mentioned a good method:

```
print(f'a is {a==1}')
```